# How to access data in cvMat

Tags: c, opencv, element

I'm trying to access data in my `cvMat`.

Here's my code:

```
// Declare
int rank = 3;
CvMat* warp_matrix = cvCreateMat(rank,rank,CV_32FC1);

// Using
cvGetPerspectiveTransform(imgSrc,imgDst,warp_matrix);

for(int i=0; i<rank; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<rank; j++)
    {
        std::cout << warp_matrix->data[i][j] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

But I catch an error:

```
error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'CvMat::<anonymous union>' and 'int')
```

And I don't know how to fix it - I try `CV_MAT_ELEM()` like this:

```
std::cout << CV_MAT_ELEM(warp_matrix,double,i,j) << std::endl;
```

And it still doesn't work (catch this error):

```
error: request for member 'cols' in 'warp_matrix', which is of pointer type 'CvMat*' (maybe you meant to use '->' ?)
```

I don't know what to do now. Can you help me ?

Comment: The title of your question is explicit that this is ***C, not C++***.  But the code example you provide is clearly C++.  (eg. `std::cout`).

Comment: Have you tried `printf( "%f ",cvmGet( warp_matrix, i, j ) );`  From ***[here](http://note.sonots.com/OpenCV/MatrixOperations.html)***

Answer (score 0):

Use macro CV_MAT_ELEM. It expects a cvMat and not a pointer to cvMat. If rather need pointers:

```
mx->data;
```

is an unnamed union of pointers (per type):

```
mx->data.ptr; // uchar
mx->data.i; // int
mx->data.s; // short
mx->data.db; // double
mx->data.fl; // float
```

Note that these are one dimensional, so mx[row][col] style access shall not work. Consider example:

```
CvMat * mx = cvCreateMat( 3, 4, CV_32FC1 );
LOG->PrintLn( "%u x %u", mx->cols, mx->rows );
for( uint rdx = 0; rdx < mx->rows; ++rdx )
{
    for( uint cdx = 0; cdx < mx->cols; ++cdx )
    {
        CV_MAT_ELEM( * mx, float, rdx, cdx ) = ( 1 + rdx ) * 10 + cdx;
        LOG->Print( "\t%.1f", mx->data.fl[ mx->cols * rdx + cdx ] );
    }
    LOG->PrintLn();
}
```

(Matrices imgSrc and imgDst are not declared in your example so I could not have produced a transformation.)